# How to create combined LETTER + ACCENT like (e + ̀) that appears like è in PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-s3, character-encoding, digital-ocean

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and I recently put mp3 files on DigitalOcean Space for flexibility. The Problem is there are some files has french or creole characters on them. However, when I can't find those files neither with AWS `s3` driver in `config/filesystem.php`, nor with direct access to the browser. It worked great before in Ubuntu FileSystem. When I copied the Song file name from DigitalOcean space I get something like :

```
song_Zenglen Live Juin 2018 Grev Bèbè_1532382400.mp3
```

Which looks the same as but is different than

```
song_Zenglen Live Juin 2018 Grev Bèbè_1532382400.mp3
```

in the Word `BeBe`. The first contains `e`+`(a character)` that when combined by the Text Editor show as `Bèbè`. The second is the character `è` on MySQL which show as `Bèbè`.

If you copy and paste the 1st and try to delete the `è` with one keypress, you will notice that ONLY THE ACCENT IS GONE and the `e` remained. But with the second, all of the `è` is gone.

And in the browser on the website page, I see the `è` as `%C3%A8` :

```
song_Zenglen%20Live%20Juin%202018%20Grev%20B%C3%A8b%C3%A8_1532382400.mp3
```

What is that HIDDEN CHARACTER that when combining with the letters put ACCENT to them?

I'm using `utf8` or `utf8mb4` for everything, except DigitalOcean Space that does not provide me a way to specifically connect with `utf8`. If someone can give me some advice while I'm investigating on it, it will be helpful.

Comment: I saw this link. I'm trying to understand it, maybe someone can faster than me. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0300

Comment: The "hidden character" is a combining grave accent, it's an alternative to using the "precomposed" version of è. What's not clear to me is what problem it's causing to you. How did you upload the files, where are you storing the names etc. You mention Amazon S3, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41331188/318758

Comment: I backed up the mp3 on my Mac, and I uploaded them directly to DigitalOcean Web interface for SPACE (Object Storage that use AWS S3 system). So each file that has the accent are now combined

Comment: @Joni `\xC3\xA8` is not a combining mark, it's a single UTF8 codepoint denoting an accented e, represented as a 2-byte sequence.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a way to put the grave accent character by code and combine it with a letter programmatically. But after I ask the Question I saw that I could copy directly the grave accent in Sublime IDE, so I was thinking that I could just preg replace for example the è with the combined one that I would paste manually and hardcode it in string in php code.

Comment: It sounds like Digital Ocean maintains the file names as they were on your Mac, which means they are in NFD ("normalization form: decomposed"). It sounds like you want to normalize the name to NFC (composed). In PHP you use the Normalizer class http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that. It looks promising. I'm gonna test it

Comment: @Joni I was doing another work. But now I try it in dev and it's ok. Thanks you're a life saver. I normalize the song path in PHP with Form Decomposed so it looks for DigitalOcean combined accent filename. I use `normalizer_normalize( $this->path, Normalizer::FORM_D );` and it found them. You can answer then I will accept your answer to help others too.

Comment: If someone is using `Normalizer` class directly in ubuntu php production be careful to check if package `php7.X-intl` is installed. There is a lot of chance that it's not. Or use condition `if(class_exists('Normalizer'))` to check before using it.